# Get Typeahead.js dropdown item for click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I've been trying to get the dropdown items which typeahead.js retrieves me by their class name.

What I'm trying to do is a function which writes a message into the console when the dropdown item is clicked, but it is not happening.

This is what I'm doing:

```
var path = "{{ route('explore.autocomplete') }}";
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    minLength: 1,
    displayKey: 'name',
    items: 3,
    dupChecker: true,
    source:  function (query, process) {
        $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
            return process(data);
        })
    },
}); 

$('input').click(function() {
    console.log('You clicked');
})
```

These are the elements which I'm trying to get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXUgy.jpg